# Why the output is like this?

Tags: c, pointers

Please can you explain me the output of the line where p=(int *)(p+1);

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int a[3]={2,3,4};
    char *p;

    p=a;
    p=(char *)((int*)(p));
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    p=(int *)(p+1);
    printf("%d",*p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you didn't format your code.

Comment: it is giving 2 0 how come 0 appear in the output.

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what you expected to get and why you think that `0` shouldn't be there?

Comment: I think you're pointing a char * at the top bits of an int. This will show zero on a little-endian platform.

Answer (score 4):

This `p=(int *)(p+1);` will increment only one byte address,since p is a char pointer.
It should be `p=(int *)(p+4);` to access next integer element.

Comment: It also depends on your compiler whether your compiler treats integer as a 4 byte or 2 byte and also the size of the char. Anyways the above logic is correct and you should increment accordingly.

Comment: @user1940987 No, not quite "exactly". This trickery with incompatible pointer types violates the strict aliasing rule, and as such, it invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Well... let's look at this step-by-step, shall we:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    /* OK, here we have an array of 3 integers. That's fine. Each
     * of these is sizeof(int) bytes, typically 4 bytes. So this
     * array would typically be 12 bytes long.
     */
    int a[3]={2,3,4};

    /* And here we have a pointer to a character. A character will
     * have a size of 1 byte.  */
    char *p;

    /* Uhm... this is suspicious. Remember, p is a pointer to
     * a character, but a points to an integer. You can't mix
     * potatoes and tomatoes (or things that are 4 bytes and things
     * which are 1 byte. That's asking for trouble!) 
     */
    p=a;

    /* Well... this is slightly pointless. And ugly. What do you
     * think this code does? If you said "nothing" you'd be right.
     */
    p=(char *)((int*)(p));

    /* OK... so here you dereference the pointer p, and get
     * back a single *character* (since p is a pointer to a 
     * character) and print that character as an integer. 
     */
    printf("%d\n",*p);

    /* Now you increment p by one element. Since p is a 
     * pointer to a character, you are actually incrementing
     * the address by one, since the size of a character is
     * 1.
     *
     * But p was made to point to an array of integers and
     * integers are larger than 1 byte. Typically, they are 
     * 4 bytes long. So now you're pointing 1 byte into an
     * integer.
     */
    p=(int *)(p+1);

    /* And now you print whatever *CHARACTER* is at that address
     * as an integer.
     */
    printf("%d",*p);

    return 0;
}
```

This annotated version of the code should help you figure out what's happening. If you need more help, consider this *conceptual* diagram, which shows you the memory right before the last `printf`. Each pair of `[]` represents one byte and arrows represent pointers:

```
  [2][0][0][0][3][0][0][0][4][0][0][0]
   ^  ^
a--'  |
p-----'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes......You know.

1.if p is a pointer to a character,p+1 means address+1

2.if p is a pointer to a integer, p +1 means address+4

if the address of a is like below

`02    00    00   00  03    00   00   00   00  04    00    00  00`

`p=(char *)p;` It means that now p is a point to a character..so p+1 means address + 1

`p=(int *)p+1;` so *p=0x03000000

yeah ,that'all .thank